# Windows 7 volume On Screen Display?

Tags: windows-7, keyboard, audio

I just upgraded my PC to Windows 7. I'd like to get back the on screen display (osd) for volume. With XP I used to see a horizontal band of green bars on the screen that showed the volume level when I adjusted it from the keyboard. Now, nothing.

The PC is a generic brand (from endpcnoise.com) and the keyboard is an IBM Thinkpad Travel USB keyboard.

I'm hoping someone can point me to a specific driver to get this working. I did look at the Lenovo site and downloaded a keyboard driver, but it didn't seem to do anything. In fact, when I go to the Control Panel and look at the drivers for my keyboard, it looks like I'm still using the generic Microsoft keyboard driver.

Comment: keyboard drivers are hit and miss. I've just got a cheap $20 Saitek and volume works with no drivers. I would try uninstalling all you keyboard drivers first, at least any you have added. windows should find any usb keyboard without any drivers. if that doesnt work then your keyboard just might just not work or its too old.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

[3RVX](https://3rvx.com/) is a skinnable volume display and controller. It shows your sound volume level with its on-screen display (OSD) and also allows you to control the volume via a skinnable slider or custom hotkeys. Supports drive eject notification, mouse hotkeys, and a wide range of customization options.

[image]

Comment: Thanks. The UI seems a bit slow to respond to volume changes from the keyboard, but overall it looks pretty slick and does what I was looking for.

Answer (score 3):

Unfortunately, 3VRX doesn't work well with 64-bit Windows. Instead, try a free app called [Sound Volume Hotkeys](http://www.softarium.com/soundvolumehotkeys/).

Comment: I'm running 3VRX v2.5 on my Windows Enterprise x64, and it's fine. Perhaps there was an update in the meantime...

Answer (score 2):

I know this is an old question, but I stumbled upon this when I was looking for a similar software solution. I have found that the [**Microsoft Mouse and Keyboard Centre**](https://www.microsoft.com/accessories/en-au/downloads/mouse-keyboard-center) adds an on-screen volume indicator, regardless of what keyboard you use. This works with 64-bit Windows. Screenshot attached.

The volume indicator shows up in the bottom right corner of your main display.

I hope this helps.

[image: On-screen volume indicator on the bottom right of main display]

Comment: I'm using an old HP internet keyboard, and installing this doesn't seem to do anything.

Comment: @Eagle-Eye that's odd. It worked using a Ducky Shine keyboard.

Comment: Worked for me using a generic wireless keyboard/touchpad combo - even though the installer complained about not detecting a device. Nice!

Comment: It looks very good, likely a Metro or Fluent design, but it doesn't work for me. What version of the application are you using? Does it only work with external keyboards? I can't find any evidence of this feature even existing anywhere else. I tried old and new versions (2, 3 and 14) I even tried reverse image searching and find no additional info or other references to this functionality. I'd love to try it out!

Comment: @Foxyz this isn't needed anymore with Windows 10 and up. It's built-in.

Answer (score 0):

From my brief research and experience it seems like Lenovo has still not released official versions of the drivers for this keyboard that will enable OSD. They do however have some Beta drivers available [here](http://www-307.ibm.com/pc/support/site.wss/MIGR-46258.html).

The display of the OSD is controlled by the drivers. I had the same problem with my Microsoft Keyboards until I loaded the Windows 7 IntelliType drivers.

Comment: Yeah, that's what I found too. Lenovo isn't up to speed and the keyboard isn't that old.

Answer (score 0):

I highly recommend **Volume²** over **3VRX v2.5**.

**Volume²** is highly customizable, stable and works well on Windows 7 x64.

[**Volume²** official website](http://irzyxa.wordpress.com/tag/volume2/)

The website is in Russian. Use Google Translate to translate it to English. **Volume²** itself has English GUI.

[image: OSD]

[image: Options]

Comment: why do you recommend it over 3VRX? You didn't give a reason why it's better. That's what would be interesting.